# How to use SVG for custom node shapes in graphviz?

Tags: svg, graphviz

I'm trying to use [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) (the `dot` command-line tool, to be more specific) to generate a SVG layout of a graph. I would like to use my [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)-generated SVG files to define node shapes, and I followed the instructions on the [graphviz tutorial](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/html/shapehowto.html). I'm outputting SVG so, in theory, this should be easy to do by declaring the shapes as `<symbol>`s and `<use>`ing them in the diagram. [This e-mail](https://mailman.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-interest/2002q1/000379.html) makes me believe that the functionality was implemented, and I just can't figure out how to use it.

I tried having a node's `image` attribute pointing to the custom shape SVG file. I also tried setting the node's `shape` to `custom` and pointing the `shapefile` to the shape SVG. `dot` complains if I put an invalid file name, and its plugin graph suggests that it can read SVG. I'm guessing that either I'm using the wrong attributes, or there's something wrong with the SVG files that I have tried.

For whatever it's worth, I do have `viewBox` set on the `<svg>` attribute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

graphviz only supports SVG input where the `width` and `height` attributes are set on `<svg>` using absolute units (pixels, inches etc.). Inkscape outputs `height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 width_in_pixels height_in_pixels"` as attributes on the `<svg>` element.

I filed a [bug report](http://www.graphviz.org/mantisbt/view.php?id=2135), and a graphviz developer pointed me to the [help for the image attribute](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dimage), which describes the requirements for using SVG in custom node shapes.

Comment: Most of the links are gone! :-( Can you please show a little example of your fixed and working code? Thx

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but this post in SO helped me:

[graphviz: Nodes of SVG images do not get inserted if output is SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819164/graphviz-nodes-of-svg-images-do-not-get-inserted-if-output-is-svg)

It seems graphviz imports only .svg with the below XML header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

And also the width/height of the SVG together with the viewbox defined, example:

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
```