# Graphviz cannot open image, Ubuntu

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am having problem including image in node in graphviz. I tried both including image in node via `image="name.svg"` and via `<IMG SRC="name.svg" />` in HTML-like label. I also tried using different image formats (svg, jpg, png), but when exporting I always get message:

```
Warning: No such file or directory while opening name.svg
Warning: No or improper image="name.svg" for node "somenode"
```

*.dot* file looks like:

```
digraph {

    node1[image="image.svg", label=""]
    
    node2[  label=
        <A
        <IMG SRC="image.svg" />> ]

    node1 -> node2 }
```

*image.svg* is located in same directory as *.dot* file (output of `ls -la`):

```
total 96
drwxrwxr-x  2 filip filip  4096 maj  8 07:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 34 filip filip  4096 maj  8 07:56 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 filip filip 85030 maj  7 17:05 image.svg
-rw-rw-r--  1 filip filip   117 maj  8 07:54 mygraph.dot
```

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

I have already looked at many other questions regarding this problem, but none of the solutions given seem to help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full complete `.dot` file as a [mcve]. Also show the output of `ls -la` in the directory you are trying to call the `dot` program. And add the command line arguments of the `dot` execution and the complete output you get from it.

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819164/graphviz-nodes-of-svg-images-do-not-get-inserted-if-output-is-svg

Comment: Thank you for advices! However solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819164/graphviz-nodes-of-svg-images-do-not-get-inserted-if-output-is-svg didn't help in my case. I managed to find the solution for me, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When retrying whole process in different ways I found how it should be done, although I don't have enough knowledge to understand why this happens.

The thing is, command `dot -Tsvg mygraph.dot > mygraph.svg` must be run from the directory where *mygraph.dot* is stored. Also, *image.svg* must be located in this same directory or in one of the subdirectories. If, for example, *mygraph.dot* is stored inside *dir1*, running

```
dot -Tsvg dir1/mygraph.dot > dir1/mygraph.svg
```

from the parent directory of *dir1* won't work.

Also, image inside HTML-like label should be inside a table:

```
node[   label=
        <<TABLE><TR><TD>
                <IMG 
                    SRC="/home/filip/dir2/images/image.svg"
                />
        </TD></TR></TABLE>>
]
```

It is possible all this is stated somewhere in the documentation and I just didn't notice.

Also, maybe worth mentioning is that on Ubuntu, if I wanted *image.svg* embedded in output file, I had to additionaly install *librsvg2-dev* and *librgraphviz-dev* packages, then run:

```
dot -Tsvg:cairo mygraph.dot > mygraph.svg
```